# xcode cocoapods cant find pod module

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I have a project that I work on one computer with. I installed it and it runs fine.

I have another computer and tried to run the project. It tells me it can't find a module...even though it says it downloaded and installed the module and I followed the same steps as the other computer

[image] 
[image]

Any ideas?

Checklist:

1. restarted xcode,
2. cleaned project,
3. updated xcode,
4. opened project from 3 workspace, folder and project,
5. built module from scheme (no problems)

Comment: Have you done all the usual things like restarting Xcode after installing the pods and cleaning your build to force a complete rebuild?

Comment: @juhan_h restarted xcode, cleaned project, updated xcode, opened project from 3 workspace, folder and project, built module from scheme (no problems). I'm at a loss....

Comment: @juhan_h Have you try to remove the `Podfile.lock` ? It will re-download Pods without knowning versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the import you are using is wrong, it should be:

```
import Reachability
```

Not:

```
import ReachabilitySwift
```